# What's in it for an alumnus in Corporate Alumni Relations?

Tags: job-change, employer-relations, company

Companies often maintain some level of Alumni relations that is in a lot of ways beneficial to the company itself.

One of many benefits of investing in an alumni network are:

- Fundraising prospects
- Free marketing and company referrals
- Brand Ambassadors

But what's in it for the alumni? What makes an alumnus want to engage in a past employer's alumni network?

**Context:**

I'm a member of a non-stock/non profit organization; now, most of the funding that the organization receives comes from donors, big and small personalities alike. I'm a software developer tasked to develop an information system - more like a small database to serve as a repository and contact management of former employees, guests, VIPs and other persons of interest that come in and out of the organization.

Setting aside the development, I'm curious about how the business model for having an alumni network works. The motivation by the company is clear - funding, branding etc., yet I don't find how it'll work given that there isn't any driving force (or at least I haven't known any) for former employees to be in contact with the organization.

If I am an alumni/former employee, visitor etc., why would I bother to be engaged in  an organization that I previously worked for? or even bother to give them my contact information, activities and whereabouts?

Comment: I didn't downvote nor mark this as spam or anything, but for some reason, this sounds like it was written by someone trying to promote their company's corporate alumni relations :O :D.... Would make things more transparent if the asker's own personal interest in this were given....

Comment: okay, i should probably give a context as to why I've asked this.

Comment: Hooray for context! Heh.

Comment: I'd suggest editing this to refer to a "former employee network" or something. The meaning of alumnus might have expanded to refer to ex employees, much to my chagrin, but it's very confusing here.

Comment: I've never heard of this concept but I assume that this is specific to non-profits? Typically employees for those are more invested in the mission so that system is presumably not that different from a donor network.

Comment: Thanks for the context! I'm curious, though; is there not someone at your organization who would be able to help you answer this question? Are you looking for an answer for yourself to decide why you should continue working with them?

Answer (score 1):

Networking always creates opportunities for everyone involved. I stay in contact with many people that I have had the pleasure of working with in the past. Many of these people have become friends with shared values and beliefs.

People I network with are all welcome to contact me if they need help with anything. We have fun sharing common interests professionally; for example, it's exciting to discuss advances in technology with others who share my passion. It's great for career growth, since I am happy to pass along job opportunities or serve as a reference when requested.

Best of all, I know that these people feel the same way as I do, so I can rely on them whenever I need help as well. A lot of success is built on the ability to maintain good relationships and collaborate well with others, and participating in Corporate Alumni Relations is a great way to achieve this.

Comment: New here and not sure how to tell who edited my answer after I updated it again, but thanks for the help :)